# Java3d shape with Antlr

Tags: antlr, antlr3

Well how to evaluate a very simple antlr grammar that does only this.

```
Box(1,2,4)
Cylinder(1,2)
```

and builds java3d shapes, (given I have already built a canvas for java3d and have the code for creating each element in java,

```
protected static BranchGroup addBox1(Float a, Float b, Float C){
    // create branch for display
    TransformGroup bodyTransform = new TransformGroup();
    BranchGroup bg = new BranchGroup();
    bg.setCapability(BranchGroup.ALLOW_DETACH);
    bg.setUserData(shapeId);
    // set transformation
    bodyTransform =  setTransformShape(0,0,0,0,0,0,0);
    // create box  
    Box tmpBox = new Box(a,b,c, Primitive.GENERATE_NORMALS |
                  Primitive.GENERATE_TEXTURE_COORDS,setAppearance(color));    
    getCoords(tmpBox);

    bodyTransform.addChild(tmpBox);
    trFormList.add(bodyTransform);
    shapeId++;
    //add box to branch
    bg.addChild(bodyTransform);
    return bg;   
   }
)
```

thanks

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "builds java3d shapes". Could you give an example? Or do you want to translate the two lines: `Box(1,2,4)` and `Cylinder(1,2)` into the protected `addBox1` method?

Comment: thanks for replying, I would like to call/embed the java code in the language so that when I write Box(1,2,4) it will call method addBox1 in the application which builds a shape, the same for Cylinder(1,2) which calls another method called addCylinder(1,2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this perhaps?

```
// ...

parse
  :  shape+ EOF
  ;

shape
  :  BOX '(' a=INT ',' b=INT ',' c=INT ')' { 
       YourClass.addBox(Float.parseFloat($a.text), Float.parseFloat($b.text), Float.parseFloat($c.text)); 
     }
  |  CYL '(' a=INT ',' b=INT ')' { 
       YourClass.addCylinder(Float.parseFloat($a.text), Float.parseFloat($b.text)); 
     }
  ;

BOX : 'Box';
CYL : 'Cylinder';
INT : '0'..'9'+;
SPACE : (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n'){skip();};

// ...
```